# Can't uninstall a USB audio device driver. (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, device-manager

I'm trying to uninstall the driver for a USB audio interface (the Steinberg in the image below), because I want to install a fresh version, since the current one is acting flaky.   For some reason a **PAIR** of these show up in Device Manager.
[image]

...If I delete them ("remove device"), as soon as I reboot they reappear.   If I delete them and try to install a new one on the spot before rebooting, the installer claims they're already installed, as you can see here ...

[image]

What do I need to do to get rid of these, what keeps putting them back when I get rid of them, and why are there two of them?

**EDIT - PS** - Tom Yan, in his answer, pointed out that I could also find the same driver under "Sound, Video and Game Controllers".  Indeed, there it was.   I "uninstalled" it from there; it disappeared from "Audio Inputs and Outputs".   But the installer insisted it was still installed.  I rebooted and tried again.  Same result.  (see attached image...)   There is no sign of this device/driver in Universal Serial Bus controllers but I **did** find a Steinberg USB controller utility in Apps and Features and that did allow me to uninstall it far enough to install a new one.  So I'm marking Tom's answer as correct.

[image]

Comment: @John  I don't understand your comment.  If I remove them in Device Manager they reappear after a reboot.   So it won't LET me install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "devices" under `Audio inputs and outputs` are not relevant in this context. They are some just "virtual" ones created by Windows from the information provided by your sound cards / controllers.

To remove the sound cards / controllers, where you should be provided an option (checkbox) to uninstall the corresponding driver, you should go to `Sound, video and game controllers`.

Also give `Universal Serial Bus controllers` a look, but most likely you would NOT find anything that you need to remove there. (I don't have this kind of "special" USB sound card to tell. For the "generic" ones there will be only a `USB Composite Device` which relys on Windows builtin "generic" driver that you do NOT need to / CANNOT uninstall.)

You may also want to take a look at `Apps`->`Installed apps` in `Settings` before any of the above. Sometimes the driver installer will install some kind of "uninstaller" for you. (For some older builds of Windows 10, you might need to go to the deprecated/hidden Control Panel instead, since `Installed apps` lists only those Windows Store apps, *IIRC*.)

Comment: Bingo.  "Sound, Video, and Game Controllers"     How is anyone supposed to know if something is "audio" or "sound"?    And since it appears in both places how is someone supposed to know which the "real" one is?  It's late here now so tomorrow morning I'll trying doing the uninstall and see if it goes away there.  And if it does I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @user316117 well the key isn't "audio vs sound", but "controllers vs I/Os" (I/O here, i.e. input/output, is kind a like "port", and a port doesn't need driver, more or less ;) )

Comment: The confusion is because it appears in BOTH of them.

Comment: @user316117 well, yeah, because you card does have I/Os. Just that the OS doesn't need to manipulate them directly but just need to know them so that it can give you and the applications information on where/what you can route audio/sound to through the controller.

Comment: I stayed up late and summarized it in an addendum to my post.  It was under Apps & Features (= Installed Apps in your answer)

Comment: @user316117 Chances are even the sound controller itself are relying on generic/builtin USB audio driver. (I suppose you didn't get a checkbox/option when you remove the controller in device manager either.) Probably the actual driver installed is for the device under `eLicenser` (a quick google seems to show that it is a Steinberg thing). Either way, the apps/control panel way is usually the best way to uninstall driver, as long as the installer of the driver provides you such a way, and I'm glad that you did it finally :)